# IAP Receipt is invalid when loaded from Sandbox user

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

This question is specific to `StoreKit` receipt validation & restore purchase testing. I made a restore purchase by calling

`SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()`

After which I got a callback with updated transactions list and internally refreshes the receipt.

`func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) { }`

Meanwhile when I tested the receipt inside `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished`,

```
  fileprivate func loadReceipt() -> String? {
    // Get the receipt if it's available
    if let appStoreReceiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL,
       FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: appStoreReceiptURL.path) {

      do {
        let receiptData = try Data(contentsOf: appStoreReceiptURL, options: .alwaysMapped)
        print(receiptData)
        let receiptString = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
        print("Receipt :", receiptString)
        return receiptString
      } catch {
        print("Couldn't read receipt data with error: " + error.localizedDescription)
      }
    }
    return nil
  }
```

Now, If I validate the above receipt using `https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt` API it gave error code `220002` which means Receipt is malformed. Also neither expiry time of receipt is set.

Is the stored receipt loading correctly? How do we make sure a valid receipt is stored ?

Comment: In order for anyone to be able to help with the `verifyReceipt` error you will need to post relevant code for calling that service.

Comment: I used [postman](https://www.postman.com/) to hit verifyReceipt API and got the error code.